# Is it possible to include Class inside ngShow?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying if it is possible to include inside the `ng-show` the `class` but I can't make it work. So my question is, is it possible?

**Sample HTML Code**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
```

**What output I desired if possible**

```
<span ng-show="{'class' : glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback}"></span>
```

Comment: Are you dynamically loading your classes? If yes, can you show us the logic?

Comment: use `ng-class` instead

Comment: thanks for the reply @one_frontend_engineer. I will read first about the ng-class if it is the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) "The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute." So it is not possible to do that with the ng-show directive.

What you are looking for is the use of ng-class, it allows you to apply a single or multiple classes to an element according to boolean expressions.

Documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

See a working sample here:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <p ng-class="{'blue': true, 'red': false}">Hello, world!</p>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alejando Moran, thanks for the answer you provided. I will further read about the ng-class reference you included. thanks

Comment: it must be `ng-class="{'blue': true, 'red': false}[expression]"` expression will return true or false